# Laravel Autocomplete using Jquery is not fetching data if the table column name isn't 'name'

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Jquery and Laravel 5.7 to make an autocomplete feature.

I have a table named 'pricings' there is no column in that table named 'name'. When I search through a keyword it returns nothing.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#search" ).autocomplete({

    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "{{url('autocomplete')}}",
        data: {
                term : request.term
         },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
           var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                //console.log(obj.city_name);
                return obj.name;
           }); 

           response(resp);
        }
    });
},
minLength: 1
 });
});
 </script>
```

**Here is my Controller:**

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->get('term');

        $result = DB::table('pricings')->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        return response()->json($result); 
    }
```

**Table Data**

[Data in my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we6w2.png)

**output**
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/953vZ.png)

But if I change my table Column name from TITLE to NAME
It returns data

If there is no column named 'name' how can I fetch data from any column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `success` callback of your `ajax`, you are checking for `name`, you should instead be looking for `title` which is the column in your Database Table.

```
        success: function(data){
           var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                //console.log(obj.city_name);
                return obj.title;  //This should be title instead of name.
            });
```